# How can I mount a drive on an ATA bridge on a mac?

Tags: mac, usb, ata

My partner's Windows PC is borked, I took out the mSATA drive and put it in an enclosure to try and recover the files. I only have a Mac.

The drive is showing up in System Information:

```
USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge:

  Product ID:   0x0578
  Vendor ID:    0x152d  (JMicron Technology Corp.)
  Version:  5.08
  Serial Number:    0123456789ABCDEF
  Speed:    Up to 5 Gb/sec
  Manufacturer: JMicron
  Location ID:  0x14600000 / 5
  Current Available (mA):   900
  Current Required (mA):    896
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
  Media:
Generic:
  Capacity: 128.04 GB (128,035,676,160 bytes)
  Removable Media:  No
  BSD Name: disk2
  Logical Unit: 0
  Partition Map Type:   GPT (GUID Partition Table)
  USB Interface:    0
  Volumes:
ESP:
  Capacity: 524.3 MB (524,288,000 bytes)
  File System:  MS-DOS FAT32
  BSD Name: disk2s1
  Content:  EFI
  Volume UUID:  12D1E7E8-5B3E-3265-9383-C6595BA93A1A
disk2s2:
  Capacity: 41.9 MB (41,943,040 bytes)
  BSD Name: disk2s2
  Content:  796BADD3-6BBF-4D9F-B631-466EB71A4965
disk2s3:
  Capacity: 134.2 MB (134,217,728 bytes)
  BSD Name: disk2s3
  Content:  Microsoft Reserved
disk2s4:
  Capacity: 786.4 MB (786,432,000 bytes)
  BSD Name: disk2s4
  Content:  Windows Recovery
disk2s5:
  Capacity: 119.14 GB (119,140,253,696 bytes)
  File System:  MS-DOS
  BSD Name: disk2s5
  Content:  Microsoft Basic Data
disk2s6:
  Capacity: 7.41 GB (7,406,444,544 bytes)
  BSD Name: disk2s6
  Content:  Windows Recovery
```

But the drives aren't being mounted by MacOS. Is it possible to access/mount the drives?

Comment: Does OSX ship with drivers for the NTFS file system? (I know it did not a few years back).

Answer (score 0):

get Tuxera NTFS for mac. it gives read/ write access to windows volumes to macs.

https://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/

i use it but have no connection to the company.

free 15 day trial, don't know if it limited but i bought it the first time i used it and had no regrets.